# Bring the Options from database table in 2nd Select box based on the value selected in 1st Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I searched a lot about this topic and found difficult approaches mostly not working. I have 2 Select boxes **(class & student)** which should be dynamically generated. After selecting the **Class**, the 2nd Select Box should show the Option Values from the **Students Table**.

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<h4>Issue Book: </h4><hr>

    <label class="control-label" for="class">Class</label>
    <select id="class" name="class" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
    <?php
        $class_query = "SELECT * FROM `classes` ";
        $class_result = mysql_query($class_query);
        do{
            $class_row = mysql_fetch_array($class_result);
            if($class_row){
                $class_id = $class_row['id'];
                $class_name = $class_row['class'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $class_id; ?>"><?php echo $class_name; ?></option>
    <?php
            }
        }while($class_row);
    ?>
    </select>

    <label class="control-label" for="student">Student</label>
    <select id="student" name="student" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Student</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <button type="submit" name="issue_book">Issue Book</button>
</form>
```

Kindly help with this, I have no knowledge of `JS` or `JQuery`. I shall be very thankful.

Comment: you want to add option value from first option in 2nd select option or get data using first select value in depend?

Comment: I want to get data from Students table depending on the Class selected from the 1st Select Box

Comment: ok wait , i will do this

Answer (score 0):

first this is your html code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<h4>Issue Book: </h4>
<hr>

<label class="control-label" for="class">Class</label>
<select id="class" name="class" class="form-control" onchange="getStudentOption(this)">
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
    <option value="class1">Class 1</option>
    <option value="class2">Class 2</option>
    <option value="class3">Class 3</option>
    <option value="class4">Class 4</option>
</select>

<label class="control-label" for="student">Student</label>
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Student</option>
</select>

<!-- Submit -->
<button type="submit" name="issue_book">Issue Book</button>
</form>
```

added a onchange function

```
<script>
function getStudentOption(input) {
    var class_name = input.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: 'class=' + class_name,
        url: 'demo.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            $('#student').html(text);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

here demo is the file name which file give you all student data so you can change this file name and path also

and this is your demo file content

```
  <?php
 if (isset($_GET) && ($_GET['class'] != '')) {

/*$class_value = $_GET['class'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM students  WHERE  class_name=" . $class_value;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$total_refs = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($total_refs > 0) {
    ?>

    <option value="">Select Student</option>

    <?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $student_name = $line['student_name'];
        $student_id = $line['student_id'];

        ?>
        <option
            value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>"><?php echo $student_name; ?></option>

        <?php
    }

    ?>

    <?php
} else { ?>

    <option value="">Select Student</option>

<?php
}*/?>
<option value="">Select Student</option>
<option value="1">Student 1</option>
<option value="2">Student 2</option>
<option value="3">Student 3</option>
<?php }
?>
```

i have added some demo content you can update data which code i have added, i am not sure which your table structure so just update condition value and filed value

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort. I have issue with the JS in this line (data: 'class_value=' + class_name,). What is the class_value? i have changed it to class as class_value was not working

Comment: please check now , this is just variable so you can change it as you want

Comment: still not working, the problem is with the demo.php getting the values from db

Comment: ok give me your code and student table , otherwise i can not understand which section issue